# Reuse Large Join Statement For several Selects

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

During a data migration (on Postgresql) I am writing I have encountered the following problem:

I have these 3 queries which basically partition the v table:

```
select v.pk from 
-- (large join statement starting with tables v and y: with v.fk_y = v.pk)
where x.unique_id = "first" or v.fk_y is null;

select v.pk, z.value from 
-- (larger join statement (extends on first join statement))
where x.unique_id = "second";

select v.pk, z.value from 
-- (larger join statement (extends on first join statement))
where x.unique_id = "third";
```

How can I avoid writing the join statements 3 times? (I could use the larger join statement also for the first select). Is there any way I can partition the table in 1 query? (I am a bit confused here about the null values I need in the first query).

My current "Workaround":

```
select v.pk, z.value, x.unique_id from 
-- (larger join statement (extends on first join statement));
```

I will create a temporary table with the select and use it in my subsequent updates and simply use where conditions on that table.

Comment: Just OR the where conditions together?

Comment: no that doesn't work, because depending on the statement I need to do different operations in my subsequent updates. (the select queries are just the subqueries for the update queries)

Comment: Have you thought about using a materialized view for the join result?

Comment: I guess I could create a materialized view, but since I would just have to delete it afterwards I am not about the advantages this would have... Also so far, we don't use views in the database...

Comment: This is a typical case for the use of plain (not materialized) view. There is no need to drop the view after use. Let it be persistent.

Comment: hi klin. I don't understand why you would want to keep the view? It will never be used again after the migration.

Comment: If not needed, drop it of course. I wanted to point out that the existence of view practically costs nothing.

Comment: so why create the view at all? Isn't it more practical just to do a temporary table because I don't have to handle deleting it? Is there a performance gain?

Comment: A temporary table is created in memory and contains all the data from the tables from which it is created. If it is large, the operation may be expensive. Creation of a view does not copy data. When you use a view the data is taken from the original tables.